# Hook for feed creation?

Tags: urls, feed

I'm looking to create a function which would be called when the blog's `/feed/?args...` URL is requested. I've been looking at `the_content_feed`, would that be correct?

Also, how would I get the `args` in the URL into my function as an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you want to do as for when you want to hook into the process. `the_content_feed` is fired for each item in your feed, so this probably isn't the one you are after.

You could use `pre_get_posts` which fires just before WordPress queries the database:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'catch_the_feed');

function catch_the_feed($query){

    if($query->is_main_query() && $query->is_feed()){
        //It's a feed!
        $variables = $query->query_vars;
    }
}
```

*untested* but `$variables` should be an array of registered query varibles and their value (usually populated from what was recieved in the url).

...or you could use `template_redirect` which is when WordPress has retrieved the posts and is ready to display them (or redirect the user to a feed template)